# Paginação Datatable Jquery

Tags: datatable

Existe a possibilidade de setar a quantidade de páginas sem ter os registros?
Eu quero uma paginação mais eficiente, carregar os dados da página quando for clicado na página.

O datatable ele carrega todos os dados criando a paginação, ee tenho um cliente que carrega 30 mil registros, isso vai deixar lento para carregar os dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe a possibilidade de setar a quantidade de páginas sem ter os registros?

Não.

> Eu quero uma paginação mais eficiente, carregar os dados da página quando for clicado na página.

É o que ele já faz. Você só precisa mudar o comportamento do Datatable.

> O datatable ele carrega todos os dados criando a paginação, ee tenho um cliente que carrega 30 mil registros, isso vai deixar lento para carregar os dados.

Vai. Por isso mesmo que você deve usar o suporte a Ajax do Datatables pra fazer essa carga de forma mais seletiva.

Por exemplo:

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var datatable = $('table').DataTable({
            order: [1, "asc"],
            processing: true,
            paging: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/Cidades/PesquisarAjax',
                type: 'POST'
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    "name": "Estado",
                    "title": "Estado",
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return full.Estado.Nome;
                    }
                },
               { "name": "Nome", "data": "Nome", "title": "Nome" },
               { "name": "CodigoIbge", "data": "CodigoIbge", "title": "Código no IBGE" },
               { "name": "CodigoSiafi", "data": "CodigoSiafi", "title": "Código no SIAFI" }
            ],
        });

        datatable.columns().every(function () {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                that
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

`/Cidades/PesquisaAjax` devolve um JSON mais ou menos assim:

```js
{
    "draw": 0,
    "data": [ /* Aqui são objetos JSON cujos nomes de propriedades são as colunas da tela, e os valores são os valores das respectivas colunas */ ],
    "recordsFiltered": 100,
    "recordsTotal": 30000
}
```

[Veja mais aqui](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

Comment: Cigano, o meu problema é com a parte do Sql Server em fazer 30 mil registros, eu tenho uma query que faz a paginação desses registros, mas do lado do datatable, eu precisava carregar 20 registros inicialmente, e quando clicar na pagina eu fazer a query e trazer os outros 20 registros da página clicada.

Comment: Então melhore sua pergunta ou faça outra.

Answer (score 0):

Eu descobri como fazer Rafael,
No lado do servidor voce coloca junto na string, que vai gerar o json, estas informações, que o ajax vai capturar no lado cliente.

```
$string["sEcho"] = 3;
$string["iTotalRecords"] = $rowCount;
$string["iTotalDisplayRecords"] = $rowCount;
echo json_encode($string);
```