# Busca de clientes por Nome/Telefone/Cpf JavaScript/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho uma pagina que lista cliente, e preciso fazer uma pesquisa por nomes, tenho o método que faz a pesquisa o problema e como integrar ele com o front-end, procurei exemplos na internet mas acho que minha falta de noção não me deixou compreender nenhum exemplo.

Aqui esta o metodo que lista os clientes no C#:

```
      public ActionResult Index(int PaginaAtual){

        ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
        clienteModel.PaginaAtual = PaginaAtual;
        int LojistaId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        int[] lojaId = this.LojaServico.GetMany(l => l.LojistaId == LojistaId).Select(l => new int[] { l.LojaId, l.Clientes.Count}).FirstOrDefault();
        int LojaId = lojaId[0];
        if(lojaId != null){
            List<ClienteLoja> clientes = this.ClienteLojaServico.GetMany(x => x.LojaId == LojaId).OrderByDescending(x => x.DataCadastro).Skip(PaginaAtual*10).Take(10).ToList();

            clienteModel.Clientes = clientes;

            clienteModel.qtdeClientes = lojaId[1];  
            //model.LojaId = loja.LojaId;
            return View(clienteModel);
        }else{
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
        }
    }
```

E este aqui é o Metodo que FARIA a busca :

```
  public ActionResult AjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, string LojaId)
    {
        int idLoja = Convert.ToInt32(SystemCriptografia.ToDescriptografaQueryString(LojaId));
        //int LojistaId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
        //var Loja = this.LojaServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == idLoja && l.LojistaId == LojistaId).Select(l => new { l.LojaId, l.Clientes }).FirstOrDefault();
        var Loja = this.LojaServico.GetMany(l => l.LojaId == idLoja).Select(l => new { l.LojaId, l.Clientes }).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<Cliente> totalClientes = new List<Cliente>();
        if (Loja != null)
        {
            totalClientes = Loja.Clientes.Where(c => c.Cliente.Ativo == true && c.Tipo == (byte)enumTipoVinculo.APP).OrderBy(m => m.Cliente.Mensagens.Where(x => x.LojaId == idLoja && x.OrigemId == 0 && x.Visualizada == false).Select(p => p.DataEnvio)).Select(a => a.Cliente);
        }

        IEnumerable<Cliente> filtroCliente;


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            string busca = param.sSearch.ToLower();
            filtroCliente = ClienteServico.GetAll().Where(x => x.Nome.Contains(busca) ||
                           x.Email.Contains(busca) || x.Telefone.Contains(busca));
        }
        else
        {
            filtroCliente = totalClientes;
        }
        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        Func<Cliente, string> orderingFunction;
        switch (sortColumnIndex)
        {
            case 1:
                orderingFunction = (c => c.Email);
                break;
            case 2:
                orderingFunction = (c => c.Telefone);
                break;
            default:
                orderingFunction = (c => c.Nome);
                break;
        }

        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
            filtroCliente = filtroCliente.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
        else
            filtroCliente = filtroCliente.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

        var displayedClientes = filtroCliente.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedClientes select new[] { c.Nome, c.Email, c.Telefone, "perfilFbLink" };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = totalClientes.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = totalClientes.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Este ultimo método já estava pronto e foi feito por outra pessoa que já não trabalha aqui mais, então estou com muitos problemas.

Aqui e minha página que mostra os cliente:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
        <!-- /.box-header -->
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5">

                </div>
                <div class="mailbox-controls" style="margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:10px">


                    <div class="pull-right" >
                        @QntdeInicial.ToString() - @QntdeFinal.ToString()
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a id="previousPage" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cliente", new {PaginaAtual = @Model.PaginaAtual -1 , Area="Lojista"})">
                                <i class="btn btn-default btn-sm  fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a id="nextPage" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Cliente", new {PaginaAtual = @Model.PaginaAtual +1 , Area="Lojista"}) ">
                                <i class="btn btn-default btn-sm  fa fa-chevron-right">
                                </i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.pull-right -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap" id="example2_wrapper">

                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <table aria-describedby="example2_info" role="grid" id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row">
                                <th aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column descending" aria-sort="ascending" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting_asc">
                                </th>
                                <th aria-label="" aria-sort="ascending" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting_asc">Nome</th>
                                <th aria-label="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Email</th>
                                <th aria-label="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Cidade</th>
                                <th aria-label="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Telefone</th>                 
                                <th aria-label="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Avaliacão</th>
                                <th aria-label="" colspan="1" rowspan="1" aria-controls="example2" tabindex="0" class="sorting">Ações</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tabela-clientes">
                            @foreach (ClienteLoja cli in Model.Clientes)
                            {
                                <tr class="odd" role="row">
                                    <td align="center" class="sorting_1">
                                        <img src="/Content/imagens/principais/no-user.png" alt="Product Image" style="height:40px">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cli.Cliente.Nome) ? cli.Cliente.Nome : "Usuario nao cadastrado")</td>
                                    <td>@(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cli.Cliente.Email) ? cli.Cliente.Email : "Email nao cadastrado")</td>
                                    <td>@if (cli.Cliente.EnderecoResidencial != null) { cli.Cliente.EnderecoResidencial.Cidade.Nome.ToString(); } else { Write("--"); } </td>
                                    <td>@(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cli.Cliente.Telefone) ? cli.Cliente.Telefone : "Telefone nao cadastrado")</td>
                                    <td>@cli.Avaliacao.ToString()</td>
                                    <td align="left">
                                        <a class="openMyModal btn btn-info" data-id='{"nome": "@cli.Cliente.Nome","email": "@cli.Cliente.Email","pessoaId": "@cli.Cliente.PessoaId", "telefone": "@cli.Cliente.Telefone","perfilFace":"@cli.Cliente.PerfilFace" }' title="Ver informacoes do usuario" href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-parametro="" data-target="#modalCliente"><i class="fa fa-user openMyModal" data-widget=""></i></a>

                                        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="@Url.Action("Conversa", "Mensagem", new {ClienteId = cli.ClienteId, Area="Lojista"})">
                                            <i class=" fa fa-envelope" title="Ver conversa com este usuario"></i>
                                        </a>

                                        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cli.Cliente.PerfilFace))
                                        {
                                            if (cli.Cliente.PerfilFace != "Nulo")
                                            {
                                                <a target="_blank" href=@cli.Cliente.PerfilFace class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook">
                                                    </i>
                                                </a>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Acho difícil alguem conseguir responder exatamente o que eu quero por ser muito especifico, mas se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz, ou uma explicação de como essas buscas podem ser feitas, já me ajudaria bastante, porque nem pesquisar sobre o assunto eu estou conseguindo.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Você está utilizando o plugin [DataTable](https://datatables.net/)?

Comment: Eu percebi que no metódo antigo era usado DataTable, por isso do metodo ser dessa forma, mas no metódo antigo trazia TODOS os clientes de uma vez, agora esta paginado certinho. 
Então tive a ideira de fazer um pesquisa por nome memso, com um outro metodo no controller do C# que traz essa mesma pagina so que apenas os clientes do filtro, não teria nenhuma atualização em tempo real, mas seria mais usavel.

Comment: Olhe [este artigo](https://www.echosteg.com/jquery-datatables-asp.net-mvc5-server-side). Ele explica como fazer o que deseja e possui o código para download. Todavia, a noite eu elaboro uma resposta completa.

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada no artigo, mas já vai dar tempo de terminar, se der para postar um resposta eu agradeço, amanha eu vou tentar implementar de acordo com o artigo ou sua resposta, de qualquer forma muito obrigado por sua ajuda .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá.

A primeira coisa será **"tipar"** os os atributos do **DataTables**. Para isso, criaremos a **ViewModel** `DatatablesViewModel`.

**DatatablesViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

///This view model class has been referred from example created by Marien Monnier at Soft.it. All credits to Marien for this class
namespace MVCDatatableApp.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A full result, as understood by jQuery DataTables.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The data type of each row.</typeparam>
    public class DTResult<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the draw parameter sent as part of the data request.
        /// Note that it is strongly recommended for security reasons that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the draw parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.
        /// </summary>
        public int draw { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
        /// </summary>
        public int recordsTotal { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data).
        /// </summary>
        public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The data to be displayed in the table.
        /// This is an array of data source objects, one for each row, which will be used by DataTables.
        /// Note that this parameter's name can be changed using the ajaxDT option's dataSrc property.
        /// </summary>
        public List<T> data { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The additional columns that you can send to jQuery DataTables for automatic processing.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class DTRow
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Set the ID property of the dt-tag tr node to this value
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string DT_RowId
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add this class to the dt-tag tr node
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string DT_RowClass
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add this data property to the row's dt-tag tr node allowing abstract data to be added to the node, using the HTML5 data-* attributes.
        /// This uses the jQuery data() method to set the data, which can also then be used for later retrieval (for example on a click event).
        /// </summary>
        public virtual object DT_RowData
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The parameters sent by jQuery DataTables in AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTParameters
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Draw counter.
        /// This is used by DataTables to ensure that the Ajax returns from server-side processing requests are drawn in sequence by DataTables (Ajax requests are asynchronous and thus can return out of sequence).
        /// This is used as part of the draw return parameter (see below).
        /// </summary>
        public int Draw { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// An array defining all columns in the table.
        /// </summary>
        public DTColumn[] Columns { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// An array defining how many columns are being ordering upon - i.e. if the array length is 1, then a single column sort is being performed, otherwise a multi-column sort is being performed.
        /// </summary>
        public DTOrder[] Order { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paging first record indicator.
        /// This is the start point in the current data set (0 index based - i.e. 0 is the first record).
        /// </summary>
        public int Start { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Number of records that the table can display in the current draw.
        /// It is expected that the number of records returned will be equal to this number, unless the server has fewer records to return.
        /// Note that this can be -1 to indicate that all records should be returned (although that negates any benefits of server-side processing!)
        /// </summary>
        public int Length { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
        /// </summary>
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom column that is used to further sort on the first Order column.
        /// </summary>
        public string SortOrder
        {
            get
            {
                return Columns != null && Order != null && Order.Length > 0
                    ? (Columns[Order[0].Column].Data + (Order[0].Dir == DTOrderDir.DESC ? " " + Order[0].Dir : string.Empty))
                    : null;
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A jQuery DataTables column.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTColumn
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Column's data source, as defined by columns.data.
        /// </summary>
        public string Data { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Column's name, as defined by columns.name.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to indicate if this column is searchable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.searchable.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Searchable { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Flag to indicate if this column is orderable (true) or not (false). This is controlled by columns.orderable.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Orderable { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Specific search value.
        /// </summary>
        public DTSearch Search { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An order, as sent by jQuery DataTables when doing AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTOrder
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Column to which ordering should be applied.
        /// This is an index reference to the columns array of information that is also submitted to the server.
        /// </summary>
        public int Column { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ordering direction for this column.
        /// It will be dt-string asc or dt-string desc to indicate ascending ordering or descending ordering, respectively.
        /// </summary>
        public DTOrderDir Dir { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort orders of jQuery DataTables.
    /// </summary>
    public enum DTOrderDir
    {
        ASC,
        DESC
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A search, as sent by jQuery DataTables when doing AJAX queries.
    /// </summary>
    public class DTSearch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Global search value. To be applied to all columns which have searchable as true.
        /// </summary>
        public string Value { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// true if the global filter should be treated as a regular expression for advanced searching, false otherwise.
        /// Note that normally server-side processing scripts will not perform regular expression searching for performance reasons on large data sets, but it is technically possible and at the discretion of your script.
        /// </summary>
        public bool Regex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Após isso, vamos criar a classe responsável por filtrar os valores de acordo com a coluna. Vamos chamar essa classe de `ResultSet.cs`.

**ResultSet.cs**

```
  public class ResultSet
    {
        public List<Customer> GetResult(string search, string sortOrder, int start, int length, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            return FilterResult(search, dtResult,columnFilters).SortBy(sortOrder).Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();
        }

        public int Count(string search, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            return FilterResult(search, dtResult, columnFilters).Count();
        }

        private IQueryable<Customer> FilterResult(string search, List<Customer> dtResult, List<string> columnFilters)
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> results = dtResult.AsQueryable();

            results = results.Where(p => (search == null || (p.Name != null && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || p.City != null && p.City.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                || p.Postal != null && p.Postal.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || p.Email != null && p.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || p.Company != null && p.Company.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) || p.Account != null && p.Account.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                || p.CreditCard != null && p.CreditCard.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))) 
                && (columnFilters[0] == null || (p.Name != null && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[0].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[1] == null || (p.City != null && p.City.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[1].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[2] == null || (p.Postal != null && p.Postal.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[2].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[3] == null || (p.Email != null && p.Email.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[3].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[4] == null || (p.Company != null && p.Company.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[4].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[5] == null || (p.Account != null && p.Account.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[5].ToLower())))
                && (columnFilters[6] == null || (p.CreditCard != null && p.CreditCard.ToLower().Contains(columnFilters[6].ToLower())))
                );

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Agora temos quase tudo preparado, então vamos para o nosso **controller**.

**HomeController**

```
 public JsonResult DataHandler(DTParameters param)
    {
        try
        {
            var dtsource = new List<Customer>();
            using (dataSetEntities dc = new dataSetEntities())
            {
                dtsource = dc.Customers.ToList();
            }

            List<String> columnSearch = new List<string>();

            foreach (var col in param.Columns)
            {
                columnSearch.Add(col.Search.Value);
            }

            List<Customer> data = new ResultSet().GetResult(param.Search.Value, param.SortOrder, param.Start, param.Length, dtsource, columnSearch);
            int count = new ResultSet().Count(param.Search.Value, dtsource, columnSearch);
            DTResult<Customer> result = new DTResult<Customer>
            {
                draw = param.Draw,
                data = data,
                recordsFiltered = count,
                recordsTotal = count
            };
            return Json(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { error = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Você pode alterar a busca para a forma que desejar, mas o importante é retornar os dados solicitados [no server-side, conforme a DOC do DataTables](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side).

Em nossa **View**, basta utilizar o **DataTables** com **server-side**, desta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#datatab tfoot th').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input type="text" />');
    });

    var oTable = $('#datatab').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": '/Home/DataHandler',
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            'data': function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
        },
        "dom": 'frtiS',
        "scrollY": 500,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "scroller": {
            loadingIndicator: false
        },
        "processing": true,
        "paging": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "columns": [
       { "data": "Name" },
       { "data": "City" },
       { "data": "Postal" },
       { "data": "Email" },
       { "data": "Company" },
       { "data": "Account" },
       { "data": "CreditCard" }
        ],
        "order": [0, "asc"]

    });

    oTable.columns().every(function () {
        var that = this;

        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            that
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();
        });
    });

});
```

Caso queira entender melhor, existe [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40406/20615) e [esta daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115429/20615) que falam do mesmo assunto.

Caso queira o código completo, pode ver o [repositório no GitHub aqui.](https://github.com/cynx/jquery-datatables1.10-mvc5-serverside)

E uma explicação mais detalhada, você pode ver o [artigo de onde eu busquei esse código.](https://www.echosteg.com/jquery-datatables-asp.net-mvc5-server-side)